# Strange Issue with "Recent" Stacks in Mountain Lion

Tags: dock

After my recent upgrade to Mountain Lion I accidentally dragged the "Recent Applications" stack off the dock and it "poofed" away... not that big a deal, I just went into Terminal and used the following command

> defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'

followed by resetting the dock with

> killall Dock
>
> exit

Then emptied the trash, shut down, and reboot for good measure...

A space for the Recent Apps is now present on the dock, but it doesn't contain anything, no matter how many apps I open.  It is right clickable to get the context menu. The same is true no matter which kind of "Recent" stack is selected.  If selected the Favorite Volumes or Favorite Items stacks work normally.

Looking through the Library there is no recent items plist.

What's my next step?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved:  After the update the Recent Items selection in System Preferences>General was set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

when I open quicktime, pictures, texedit or word docs 
at least 10 previous files open up at the same time
this is really confusing and annoying 
although recent items is set to none

why does mountain lion have the same bugs as the first versions of lion 
why did apple even add these silly windows features ...

Comment: I haven't had that issue... Is the "Close windows when quitting an application" option checked in the System Preferences>General menu?